# Touchpad not working on Lenovo ThinkPad E14 with Ubuntu 22.04.1

Tags: mouse, 22.04, touchpad, lenovo, thinkpad

I recently upgrade a *Lenovo ThinkPad E14 Gen 2* laptop to Ubuntu 22.04.1 from 20.04. And the touchpad mouse has stopped responding altogether. (It was working before.)

Things I tried:

1. I ran `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. Nothing changed after successful upgrade.
2. Checked Lenovo's BIOS menu to see it touchpad is enabled. It was enabled.

Please let me know what can be done to fix this?

`uname -a` output:

```
Linux adarsh-ThinkPad-E14-Gen-2 5.15.0-52-generic #58-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 13 08:03:55 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the touchpad was disabled.
Can you run the below in a terminal and see if it now works (if you're running Gnome):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad send-events enabled
```

Comment: What worked in my case is resetting the BIOS settings. I am not sure why it wasn't working before as touchpad was already enabled in BIOS. However, resetting it did the job. Thank you!

Comment: I did what prime_mover said above and strangely enough it worked. I have a suspicion I would have do this again in few days or week.

Answer (score 0):

According to bullet No. 7 from [Ubuntu Wiki Debugging Touchpad Detection](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection#General_work_flow_for_Triagers_and_debugging_tips)

```
$ sudo modprobe psmouse
$ lsmod | grep psmouse
psmouse               212992  0
```

Worked for me.